# Android volley login session

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using RESTful service. After I login I cannot access other services with the app. It says I am not logged in. I believe I am doing something wrong with the HttpClientStack.. Here is the code..

```
public class HttpClientStackObject {
    public static DefaultHttpClient httpClient;
    public static HttpClientStack httpClientStack;

    public static HttpClientStack getHttpClientStack() {

        if(httpClientStack == null){
            httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httpClientStack = new HttpClientStack(httpClient);
        }
        return httpClientStack;
    }
}
```

**Login.java**

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this, HttpClientStackObject.getHttpClientStack());

jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                            Request.Method.POST, URL, jsonOb,
                            new ResponseListener(), new ErrorListener());
                    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Comment: What Rest service are you connecting to? You really didn't post any useful code or error messages or anything, but to take a blind guess: the Login service will return some kind of token which you need to pass into subsequent requests.

Comment: The response error code is 500.

Comment: Did you say Not Authenticated? That should be 403. Again, you need to provide more information.

Comment: I have posted another question in more detail. Please have a look.

Comment: Where? Not sure what you're referring to...